# Check for S3 directory existence in Databricks notebook

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I am working in Databricks and I am trying to grab parquet data from S3 instances that are ordered in a sequence, except some parts of the sequence are missing. So the file system might look like this:

```
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/18',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/17',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/16',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/15',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/14',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/13',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/12',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/10',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/09',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/08',
 's3a://databricks-data/STAGING/07'
```

You'll notice that `11` is missing and this is where the problem comes in. There are occasionally some of these folders missing, and it's not systematic or predictable. So, coming from a Python background, I figured I could create a list of folders from a sequence and then test whether such a folder exists, and if so, read the data, if not, skip. Something like this:

```
paths = ["s3a://databricks-data/STAGING/" + str(ii) for ii in range(100)]
paths = [p for p in paths if p.exists()] #**this check -- "p.exists()" -- is what I'm looking for**
df = spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```

Does anyone know how I can check if a folder/directory exists in Databricks? I've tried using `dbutils`, but either I'm working with a different version or I don't know what I'm doing (maybe both), because nothing works. I'm pretty new to Databricks so let me know if I can clarify this question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dbutils.fs.ls` for example to implement such function:

```
def path_accessible(path):
  try:
    dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    return True
  except:
    pass

  return False
```

and then use it:

```
paths = [p for p in paths if path_accessible(p)]
```

Please note, that it checks if the path is accessible - you may not have access because of invalid credentials, etc. - you can improve it by adding corresponding `except` clauses.

P.S. If you're doing that to load the increments of data, I would recommend to consider Structured Streaming (even in the Trigger.Once mode) with [Auto Loader](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/02/24/introducing-databricks-ingest-easy-data-ingestion-into-delta-lake.html) - it could be better from performance point of view if you have a lot of files in your directories.

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to access `dbutils.fs` at all. I execute `import dbutils`, and  `dir(dbutils)` yields `['Console', 'DBUtils', 'FileInfo', 'Iterable', 'ListConverter', 'MapConverter', 'MountInfo', 'NotebookExit', 'Py4JJavaError', 'SecretMetadata', 'SecretScope', 'WidgetsHandlerImpl', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'absolute_import', 'makeTensorboardManager', 'namedtuple', 'print_function', 'range', 'stderr', 'stdout', 'string_types', 'sys', 'zip']`. Maybe I'm working with a different version of Databricks or something? I'm not sure.

Comment: OK, so, I was confused about how to use `dbutils`; it should not be imported. Rather, it is part of a Databricks notebook on startup. Given this, your solution works perfectly, thanks! As for using Auto Loader, I'll have to look into this more. Do you have any recommended reading for using this with S3 buckets that are not meant to be read automatically?

Comment: Documentation should be enough